# DataFrame from jagged array

Tags: python, list, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a dataset that looks like follows:

```
date = ['01/01/2001','02/01/2001']
countries = [['US', 'UK', 'AU'],['CN']]
```

so basically the data ought to look like:

```
def flatten(array):
    return sum(array,[])
pd.DataFrame({'date': flatten([[date[0]]*3, [date[1]]]), 'country': flatten(countries)})
# Which Returns:
    country date
0   US  01/01/2001
1   UK  01/01/2001
2   AU  01/01/2001
3   CN  02/01/2001
```

The above seems like an inefficient way to implement this. The length of the `date` and `countries` arrays are exactly the same. Basically the `date` needs to be repeated by the length of the sub array.

Is there an elegant way of doing this in Pandas? Or do I need to preprocess the arrays similar to what I have done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try my 1-liner:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(chain(*[list(product([x],y)) for x, y in zip(date, countries)])), columns= ['date',"countries"])
```

**Explanation:**

Basically [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html) is a perfect choice in this case to tangle the problem in a more **`Pythonic`** way:

```
from itertools import chain, product
df = pd.DataFrame(list(chain(*[list(product([x],y)) for x, y in zip(date, countries)])), columns= ['date',"countries"])

df
Out[56]: 
         date countries
0  01/01/2001        US
1  01/01/2001        UK
2  01/01/2001        AU
3  02/01/2001        CN
```

---

### Updates:

**More Detailed Explanation**:

- **Step 1:** Use list comprehension, `zip`, `itertools.product` to `product` the two input list:

  `[list(product([x],y)) for x, y in zip(date, countries)]
  Out[59]: 
  [[('01/01/2001', 'US'), ('01/01/2001', 'UK'), ('01/01/2001', 'AU')],
   [('02/01/2001', 'CN')]]`
- **Step 2:** Unpack/flatten `list of lists`, using `itertools.chain()`.

  `list(chain(*[list(product([x],y)) for x, y in zip(date, countries)]))
  Out[60]: 
  [('01/01/2001', 'US'),
  ('01/01/2001', 'UK'),
  ('01/01/2001', 'AU'),
  ('02/01/2001', 'CN')]`
- **Step 3:** Form the `DataFrame`:

  `df = pd.DataFrame(list(chain(*[list(product([x],y)) for x, y in zip(date, countries)])), columns= ['date',"countries"])`

Comment: could you put a short description or link to what chain and * means?

Comment: @Sachin_ruk, no problem. I will update shortly, come back in 6 mins.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
    DD = []
    for x, y in zip(date, countries):
        for z in y: DD.append([x,z])

    pd.DataFrame(DD, columns= (['date',"countries"]))

            date countries
    0  01/01/2001        US
    1  01/01/2001        UK
    2  01/01/2001        AU
    3  02/01/2001        CN
```